# VideoView: how to always show MediaController while playing video

Tags: android, video, android-videoview, mediacontroller

I have a very simple task - just to show playback controls while playing video on `VideoView`. But I can't solve it.

Here is the piece of code that I use for initializing `VideoView` and setting `MediaController`:

```
videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(videoUrl));
MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
videoView.setKeepScreenOn(true);
videoView.setOnPreparedListener(mp -> {
    progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    videoView.start();
    mediaController.show(0);
});
```

The thing is that `mediaController.show(0)` doesn't give any effect. Controls just show up for 3 seconds and then disappear.

Also I have tried to override MediaController's `hide()` method:

```
@Override public void hide() {}
```

Well, it works - controls never hide, but unfortunately hardware 'back' button stops working. Without override hardware 'back' button on first tap close media controls, on second tap - brings user to previous screen, as expected.

Are there any working solutions?

Answer (score 9):

If you try to display media controler buttons as below :

```
    videoView.start();
    mediaController.show(0);
```

for some reasons show(0) is ignored.

But if you delay the call of show(0) a few milliseconds, it will work :

```
....
public Handler handler = new Handler();
....
videoView.start();
handler.postDelayed(
            new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    mediaController.show(0);
                }},
            100);
```

It looks a bit buggy to me and if it is design intent, it is poorly documentated.

Answer (score 4):

MediaController hide in 3 seconds by default, so you need to override `hide()` to display MediaController

```
videoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this) {
    @Override
    public void hide()
    {
       mediaController.show();
    }

    }); 

videoView.setMediaController(mc);
```

Comment: Sorry, I made typo in my question, I also have tried overriding hide() method. I have fixed question text.

Comment: I have tried to put show() inside hide() - but 'back' button still doesn't work

Comment: That's the another problem check activity's onBackPressed  method

Comment: I have checked onBackPressed() method - and it is never called with override. But without override it enters immediately.

Comment: then override and user finish

Comment: Sorry, what did you mean? I already have tried to override onBackPressed() - but it is never called if I override MediaController's hide() method. If I don't override MediaController's hide() method then onBackPressed() it called on 'back' button press.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113018/discussion-between-nirav-ranpara-and-ruslan).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [u2gilles](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3131604/u2gilles)'s answer, I encountered that the delay was too short resulting "play" symbol being displayed instead of the "pause" symbol.

Modify the handler's delay to ~250ms to fix it.